# Create window without a browser

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to make a game in javascript without any ide or game engine or even without a browser I installed node js but I have no clue how to make a window or where to start I've tried search how to make a window with javascript but it keeps referring to the browser and I want to make it without so like and exe instead of HTML but in javascript sorry I'm not very good at explaining and this explanation is all over the place

Comment: `Node.js is server-side. It does not have a document. Try running "typeof(window)" in the REPL. You get "undefined", meaning window is not defined.`

Comment: Check out [electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).  It gives you a web engine for your user interface and nodejs for your backend and is cross platform.

Comment: You can use [Node-GTk](https://github.com/timheap/node-gtk) to use the GTk library from Node.js to display local windows.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Node.JS is a server-side runtime, it is not meant to do any graphics or such. You might be able to process user input and do game logic but you don't really have any way to actually display your game state.
(I'm aware of bindings like Node-GTK and such, but these are just bindings to C/C++ libraries, they are not really JavaScript or NodeJS so although you can use them, i wouldn't count them, as they are not really JavaScript)

And second of all, JavaScript is an interpreted language, it can't be compiled to an .exe, there are things like electron that allow you to embed a chromium instance to run your JavaScript code, but that's about it.

making games with JavaScript never really reached anything outside of browsers, let that be with Adobe Flash or HTML5, JavaScript is meant to run on browsers you can't really change that.